# Can I Talk to My Active Directory Certificate Authority?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got a lot of servers. Most of those servers can talk to my AD's Certificate Authority, but some can't. When a server can't talk to the CA, calls to `Get-Certificate` crash the Powershell session. I'd like to wrap `Get-Certificate` in another function, which checks to see if the host can communicate with the AD Certificate Server. I'm not sure how to do that.

The following will verify connectivity to an ADCS server:

```
certutil.exe -config - -ping
```

Unfortunately, this brings up a Window, which I can't script from Powershell. It's a cool feature, but I need something script-able.

I believe I can use the Active Directory Certificate Services Admin. module ([adcsadministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adcsadministration/?view=win10-ps)), but I'd really rather not have that dependency if I can help it.

Is there anything else? If so, what?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Maybe use a `try{} catch {}` for your `Get-Certificate` call?

Comment: I'd assumed there was nothing to catch because of how fantastically Powershell crashed; Posh window closes. Let me double check that I can't catch something. I'll report back.